# Trying to create a custom UITableView and cell for for some reason table is showing bars

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]I'm trying to create a custom UITableView for some reason the table is showing the bars below. Does anyone know how to get rid of those bars?

Here's what my code for my TableViewController looks like as well.

```
//
//  TableTableViewController.swift
//  CarApp
//
//  Created by Lillybridge, Kevin on 2/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 RS Design Lab. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

struct cellData {
    let cell : Int!
    let text : String!
    let image : UIImage!
}

class TableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var arrayOfCellData = [cellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell
    print("how many times is this being called")
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Based on the information you provided, it looks fine. Can you supply more information?

Comment: What do you mean by "bars"?  I see lines going across your picture, and I see lines below the picture.  Which of those are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: @Harris the tableview cell lines are crossing through his image because his image is taking up multiple cells.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`? Without using this multiple cells will be loaded each time `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` is called even if you only have 1 cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none //gets rid of separator lines
    tableView.rowHeight = 75 //the height of the nib view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to setup the cell height. Otherwise better solution is drag and drop a UIView on the header of TableView thats it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason the image takes up the size that it does. Cell height will not help because it is taking up not one cell, but many. It seems like you are adding the image to the view itself, rather than the cell.

As a solution,

1. Make **sure** that an individual cell has the image added t it, rather than the view
2. Once that is done, set up **constraints** on the image so that is is bound to the dimensions of its parent cell.
3. Make sure you have set the cell height using `tableview.rowHeight` or even `tableview.estimatedRowHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Changing the "separator" in the inspector seemed to do the trick. I will try setting the height though as well since I want to add more cells. Thanks!

[image]